# How check if a video-id exists inside the table or not

Tags: jquery

I have a table as shown below , I am trying to check if a video-id exists inside the table or not

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <table class="mytable1 table table-bordered table-hover" id="videosfromtagstable">
       <tbody class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
           <tr class="existingvideos">
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Video</th>
          </tr>
          <tr video-id="6" class="newvideos" style="display: table-row;">
              <td>One</td>
              <td><a href="xxx" target="_blank">xxx.jpg</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr video-id="48" class="newvideos">
              <td>Two</td>
              <td><a href="xxx" target="_blank">xxx.jpg</a></td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am checking it this way , this is working, but could you please let me know if this the correct and efficient procedure?

```
var checkvalue =  checkifVideoExists(48);
alert(checkvalue);

function checkifVideoExists(videoid) {
    var flag = false;
    $('#videosfromtagstable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('video-id') == videoid) {
            flag = true;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/37/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not efficient way. Better select element via it's attribute:

```
function checkifVideoExists (videoid) {
    return $('#videosfromtagstable [video-id="'+videoid+'"]').length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No dont need to loop and all, you can simply use attribute selector to find the element and check it length, if it is 0 then no such element exists other wise they do.

```
function checkifVideoExists(videoid)
{
    var el = $('#videosfromtagstable > tbody  > tr[video-id="'+videoid+'"]').length;
    return el!=0;
}
```

Read more about attribute selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `video-id` is not a valid attribute and its use will make your HTML invalid. Instead you should use `data-*` attributes to store custom metadata with an element.

To achieve what you need more effectively you can use `filter()` to find the element with the required attribute. Try this:

```js
var checkvalue = checkifVideoExists(48);
console.log(checkvalue);

function checkifVideoExists(videoid) {
  var $tr = $('#videosfromtagstable > tbody > tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('video-id') == videoid;
  });
  return $tr.length != 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portlet-body">
  <table class="mytable1 table table-bordered table-hover" id="videosfromtagstable">
    <tbody class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
      <tr class="existingvideos">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Video</th>
      </tr>
      <tr data-video-id="6" class="newvideos" style="display: table-row;">
        <td>One</td>
        <td><a href="xxx" target="_blank">xxx.jpg</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-video-id="48" class="newvideos">
        <td>Two</td>
        <td><a href="xxx" target="_blank">xxx.jpg</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for putting the data attributes inside the html .

Comment: I've upvoted this due to the first lines. The code isn't optimal. You should use `.filter('[data-video-id=<value>]').length > 0;`, like on the other answers.

Comment: I disagree. It doesn't have to create a metric ton of jQuery objects to test an attribute. That should speed things up.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that code is pretty much equivalent. jsPerf is down at the moment so I can't provide you with a test of it, however in some browsers providing a function is quicker than providing a string attribute for the selector engine.

Comment: Then use `.filter(function(){ return this.getAttribute('data-video-id') === videoid; })`. That should speed it up a bit more.